# Bash - cannot stat the last file created in a for...do loop

Tags: bash, stat

In a bash script (on Ubuntu 22 if it matters) I have a function which, executed from within a for...do loop, is given a filename to execute some SQLplus <query_name>.sql and store the results in <query_name>.csv

I added a little bit of a function to check success and to print out the file size of the csv it has just created.

BUT...it runs through this for three queries and reports the file size in the success message no problem. But for the fourth and final one it throws an error saying "Cannot statx: no such file or directory". I can see it's there. As an alternative I make the whole process list the files in the directory and it appears.

Any idea why it might not be doing the last one the same way.

Here's the code for the run_query() and success_file() functions which I think is all you need to see what I am doing:

[Edited to show the entire script file rather than just the snippet]

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/overnights/scripts/.globals/.filenames
source ~/overnights/scripts/.globals/.creds
source ~/overnights/scripts/.globals/.commands.sh

echo "============================================================================="
echo "=  Starting to fetch Banner data                                            ="
echo "============================================================================="

# cleandrop() called from each sql script execution to finish the whole process if one file fails.
cleandrop () {
  echo "`date`: Problems connecting to or fetching from Oracle. Cleaning up and exiting."
  rm -f ${IN_BANNER}/*
  cd $SCRIPT_DIR
  exit 1
}

# Displays confirmations of which file we have just processed.
success_file () {
    size=$(stat -c%s "$2")
    echo "`date`: SQL script executed successfully for $1"
    echo "`date`: Output file saved to $2 (${size} bytes)."
    echo
}

# Given a query name from the array "queries" performs the query and saves the output.
run_query () {
    SQL="${BANNER_SCRIPTS}/$1.sql"
    CSV="${IN_BANNER}/$1.csv"
    echo "`date`: Beginning ${SQL} processing."
    sqlplus64 -S "${OUSER}/${OPASS}@//${OHOST}:${OPORT}/${OSID}" @${SQL}

# Check the exit status of sqlplus to see if the SQL script ran successfully
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
      success_file ${SQL} ${CSV}
    else
      cleandrop
    fi
}

# Try a connection just to make sure it works first otherwise exit
echo "exit" | sqlplus64 -L "${OUSER}/${OPASS}@//${OHOST}:${OPORT}/${OSID}" | grep Connected > /dev/null

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
   cleandrop
else
  echo "`date`: Connection checked okay, proceeding to fetch Banner data."
fi

# Remove files from previous runs if they exist.
cd $IN_BANNER

signal="${IN_BANNER}/DONE.txt"

if [[ -f "$signal" ]]
then
    echo "`date`: Removing signal file ${signal}"
    rm -f $signal
    echo "`date`: Removing any previous data files in ${IN_BANNER}"
    echo
    rm -f ${IN_BANNER}/*.csv
fi
rm -f *

# Set up the array of query names to execute with run_query()
queries=( ora_SRS_PEOPLE
          ora_SRS_COURSES
          ora_SRS_ENROLS
          ora_SRS_STAFF
          )

for query in "${queries[@]}"
do
    run_query ${query}
done

# drop in a signal file so other processes can tell if the downloads have completed.
echo "`date`: Creating completion signal file ${signal}"
touch ${signal}
echo
echo  "`date`: Listing of data files collected in ${IN_BANNER}"
ls -lh ${IN_BANNER}

cd ${SCRIPT_DIR}
echo
echo "`date`: overnights_oracle.sh completed"
exit 0
```

...and here it the output I see:

```
=============================================================================
=  Starting to fetch Banner data                                            =
=============================================================================
Sat Oct  7 15:55:53 BST 2023: Connection checked okay, proceeding to fetch Banner data.
Sat Oct  7 15:55:53 BST 2023: Removing signal file /home/p0071665/overnights/data/downloads/banner/DONE.txt
Sat Oct  7 15:55:53 BST 2023: Removing any previous data files in /home/p0071665/overnights/data/downloads/banner

Sat Oct  7 15:55:53 BST 2023: Beginning /home/p0071665/overnights/scripts/sql/banner/ora_SRS_PEOPLE.sql processing.
Sat Oct  7 15:57:54 BST 2023: SQL script executed successfully for /home/p0071665/overnights/scripts/sql/banner/ora_SRS_PEOPLE.sql
Sat Oct  7 15:57:54 BST 2023: Output files saved to /home/p0071665/overnights/data/downloads/banner/ora_SRS_PEOPLE.csv (10776253 bytes).

Sat Oct  7 15:57:54 BST 2023: Beginning /home/p0071665/overnights/scripts/sql/banner/ora_SRS_COURSES.sql processing.
Sat Oct  7 15:58:04 BST 2023: SQL script executed successfully for /home/p0071665/overnights/scripts/sql/banner/ora_SRS_COURSES.sql
Sat Oct  7 15:58:04 BST 2023: Output files saved to /home/p0071665/overnights/data/downloads/banner/ora_SRS_COURSES.csv (3992287 bytes).

Sat Oct  7 15:58:04 BST 2023: Beginning /home/p0071665/overnights/scripts/sql/banner/ora_SRS_ENROLS.sql processing.
Sat Oct  7 16:01:07 BST 2023: SQL script executed successfully for /home/p0071665/overnights/scripts/sql/banner/ora_SRS_ENROLS.sql
Sat Oct  7 16:01:07 BST 2023: Output files saved to /home/p0071665/overnights/data/downloads/banner/ora_SRS_ENROLS.csv (26717546 bytes).

Sat Oct  7 16:01:07 BST 2023: Beginning /home/p0071665/overnights/scripts/sql/banner/ora_SRS_STAFF.sql processing.
Sat Oct  7 16:01:11 BST 2023: SQL script executed successfully for /home/p0071665/overnights/scripts/sql/banner/ora_SRS_STAFF.sql
Sat Oct  7 16:01:11 BST 2023: Output files saved to /home/p0071665/overnights/data/downloads/banner/ora_SRS_STAFF.csv ( bytes).

Sat Oct  7 16:01:11 BST 2023: Creating completion signal file /home/p0071665/overnights/data/downloads/banner/DONE.txt

Sat Oct  7 16:01:11 BST 2023: Listing of data files collected in /home/p0071665/overnights/data/downloads/banner
total 41M
-rw-r--r-- 1 p0071665 p0071665    0 Oct  7 16:01 DONE.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 p0071665 p0071665 3.9M Oct  7 15:58 ora_SRS_COURSES.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 p0071665 p0071665  26M Oct  7 16:01 ora_SRS_ENROLS.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 p0071665 p0071665  11M Oct  7 15:57 ora_SRS_PEOPLE.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 p0071665 p0071665 1.2M Oct  7 16:01 ora_SRS_STAFF_ENROLS.csv
```

And here's what I get in the console when I run it:

```
stat: cannot statx '/home/p0071665/overnights/data/downloads/banner/ora_SRS_STAFF.csv': No such file or directory
```

And yet I know the file is there. I can move and copy it, it lists in an ls -al etc.

I wondered if I had to do something to "close" the file before stat could find it, but I added a "touch" and "delete" a signalling file before it does the stat to no avail. It's not exactly critical but it's bugging me why it doesn't work on just the one element of the array of queries to run.

Cheers, Jock

Comment: What's the first line of the script? (It should be `#!...`)

Comment: Start by replacing instances of `command` in backticks with `$(command)`. Also double-quote your variables when you use them, so instead of `$SQL`, `"$SQL"`. The `{ }` braces are usually not needed around variable names and rarely add value

Comment: Do your file names contains spaces, newlines, tabs, or other non alphanumeric or non-ASCII characters What is the problematic file name? Where is this for loop you mention? How is the script launched?

Comment: It is #!/bin/bash The script runs fine except for this one little quirk. I merely provided a snippet with the two relevant functions.

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't enough: the most relevant parts are i) how the script is launched, ii) how the functions are called and with what arguments and iii) what the actual problematic file names are. I can see you're not quoting the `${CSV}`, so that would break if the file name has whitespace, but showing us the actual file names and full script (or, better, a minimal example of the script that reproduces the problem) would really help us help you as it would let us reproduce the issue locally.

Comment: Changes the OP to include the entire script and its output.

Comment: May I suggest to NOT `rm -f *` without giving an explicit path.  If you accidentally run your script in the wrong directory, THIS WILL HURT!

Comment: Well spotted! I had actually taken it out and replaced it with the more specific one above but not deleted it. It serves no purpose now where it is except to bork my system if run fro mthe wrong place :)

Comment: With commands like `rm -f $signal` in your code I really really would recommend you get into the habit of double-quoting your variables when you use them. `rm -f "$signal"` is so much safer

Comment: Oh my! Well spotted. So that's set up in the SQLplus query file being executed in the sqlplus64 command and I had forgotten to "standardise" it when I changed the one in the shell script. I had better check that later in the whole overnights process or it might not get loaded into my MySQL staging database and all the staff risk being unenrolled from the courses they are in charge of!

Comment: There isn't a `ora_SRS_STAFF.csv` so the error message is correct

Comment: Do you want to put that in as an "answer" so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it maybe a typo in your code. There isn't a `ora_SRS_STAFF.csv` so the error message is correct:

> ```
> -rw-r--r-- 1 p0071665 p0071665    0 Oct  7 16:01 DONE.txt
> -rw-r--r-- 1 p0071665 p0071665 3.9M Oct  7 15:58 ora_SRS_COURSES.csv
> -rw-r--r-- 1 p0071665 p0071665  26M Oct  7 16:01 ora_SRS_ENROLS.csv
> -rw-r--r-- 1 p0071665 p0071665  11M Oct  7 15:57 ora_SRS_PEOPLE.csv
> -rw-r--r-- 1 p0071665 p0071665 1.2M Oct  7 16:01 ora_SRS_STAFF_ENROLS.csv
> ```

Comment: Thanks, @chris-davies. A case of not seeing the wood for the trees! I've now corrected it and will need to check through other bits of code to make sure that where the CSV is being used I didn't change all that as well! I'm going to go through the code as well to implement your suggested changes.